# Android static IP ethernet on head unit

Tags: android-10, ip-address, ethernet, automotive-head-unit

I need to set static IP on an Android 10 head unit where there is no ethernet settings page enabled so I couldn't set it by the touch panel.

I try to set the address with adb command (`adb root`) and I was able to set it by using `ifconfig eth0 <static_ip_address>`. But at the boot, the system forgot this setting.

Where could I set it in a general configuration file that set the static IP configuration permanently?